# Using windows 8 desktop from windows phone

Tags: windows-8

Can i actually use my windows 8 desktop from my Nokia Lumia phone which has Windows Phone 8 installed and also both my devices synced with my Microsoft account?

Comment: How can a Lumia have Windows 8 Installed!?

Comment: @AkshatMittal I made the editing changes.It's Windows Phone 8 and not Windows 8.

Comment: Why was this closed?

Comment: @CalebJares Windows Phone is off topic for SuperUser (as are all smartphones); There is http://windowsphone.stackexchange.com/ where it would be on topic, if you're still in need of help?

Answer (score 1):

You can use the [Remote Desktop](http://www.windowsphone.com/en-us/store/app/remotedesktop/e2af408b-555a-e011-854c-00237de2db9e) application to do this, make sure you set up a [Remote Desktop Connection](http://windows.microsoft.com/en-US/windows-vista/Remote-Desktop-Connection-frequently-asked-questions) on your Windows 8, which you can do by right clicking My Computer (or going to System in the Control Panel) and then go to the Remote Settings tab where you can configure it.

Comment: Yes there's even team viewer application. But is there a direct way to access my windows 8 desktop from my windows phone 8?

Comment: No, there isn't.